# How to find the base of this expression?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, number-systems

I need to determine the radix of the numbers for make this expression true

15 = 8

How I can do that?

Comment: If you mean that the same number can be expressed as both "$15$" to base $n$ and as "$8$" to base $n$, then there is no such number. If this is not what you mean, what **do** you mean?

Comment: The equation is not true. The RHS is $8_{10}$. The number of the  LHS has at least the base $6$. The minimum of the LHS is $5_{10}+6_{10}=11_{10}$.